# HTML javascript getBoundingClientRect: need rectangle regardless of scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I want to determine the rectangle that encloses an element, but getBoundingClientRect() is relative to the current viewport (rectangle top and left, for example, change depending on scroll).

Is there any method that returns the rectangle relative to the page origin, regardless of the page scroll?

Comment: If you want it relative to an other element, just substract its rect values to the ones of your relative element, and if you want it relative to the top left corner of the document, just add it to pageYOffset and pageXOffset ? (`var absolutePosTop  = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYoffset;`)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, this should help solve my problem